# 32 bit CentOS bootable USB drive is not detected in UEFI mode

Tags: linux, centos, uefi, 32bit

I am trying to install CentOS on my intel compute stick which has 32 bit architecture using Intel Atom Processor.

(Intel compute stick CS125 with 32 Bit Atom processor)

The link to kernel is here:
http://isoredirect.centos.org/altarch/7/isos/i386/

I download the ISO and burnt it to my usb drive (/dev/sdb and not /dev/sdbX) using dd command. However in the UEFI boot screen, this bootable iso is not detected.

I did not have issues with normal CentOS. It detected fine and took me to installation menu. But since that was 64 bit, it was pretty much useless.

Why doesnt 32 bit CentOS ISO detect and start the install in UEFI mode?

Comment: Are you using "secure boot" setting in your BIOS?

Comment: @Paradox Nope - that is the first thing I disabled. Just to add I burnt an alpine 32 bit image to usb and that booted perfectly fine. I am now venturing to fully install it and make it bootable from disk, but id love to be able to install CentOS for its sheer power.

Comment: Could you go further on the details of your system (Intel Compute Stick model, CentOS release, ISO used, etc.) so it will be easier to help you out?

Comment: @Paradox The link to CentOS is in the question. It is alt arch i386. Device is Intel compute stick CS125 with 32 bit  intel atom

Comment: Could you edit your question to add these details? (It is difficult to keep track of this in the comments and these information could be useful for future reference for others readers. Regarding my request on CentOS release/ISO, I just wanted to be sure you were using 1810 release and which one e.g. "Minimal".

Comment: @Paradox Thanks I will edit the question. And yes I tried minimal.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reports of this issue.  I was able to use YUMI to boot the ISO and install CentOS 7 i386 from an external USB hardrive.  Be sure to format the drive as NTFS because Fat32 cannot support the large file and YUMI does not support exFat.